# Empty space between two ground objects in unity (Infinite scrolling)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an endless runner which has infinite scrolling ground. I am using two same ground objects and resetting their position after it's scrolled to left more than its width. However, when it's scrolling there's a small gap between two ground objects. How can I fix this?

[image: Issue]

[image: ground controller script]

[image: collider and rigid body attached to ground object]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Why is your ground a **dynamic** rigidbody? Are you expecting it to move? Otherwise make it **static**!

Comment: @derHugo yes..ground is moving. This is an endless runner game.

Comment: **how** is the ground moving and why is it not kinematic then?

Comment: @derHugo It's moving because I added a velocity in the Start function and I have no idea about what kinematic is!

Comment: Well I think the main issue is you moving the floor by physics .. kinematic means you rather move it vis code and it doesn't respond to physics .. in your case most probably collision with the other floor(s)

Comment: Alternatively you could put your floor on a layer and configure that layer to not collide with itself